# routing nodejs invalid arg type

Tags: node.js

im following some instuctuctions from my teacher to return a view using nodejs only it now gives the error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type undefined

i can't find whats wrong can somebody help me?

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res){
    const url = req.url;
    if (url === '/') {
        fs.readFile('/view/index.ejs', function (err, data) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue, but only working with `fs.read()` method.
I got same type of error, and problem was in my node version.

For this function `fs.read()` I needed node version at least 13 or newer.

After updating node problem was solved.

Maybe it will be helpful to someone.